# How to change magento connect url

Tags: magento-1.9

I have to change magento connect manager url sitename.com/downloader to sitename.com/customurl
but don't have a idea how to change it can anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

Just rename the folder.
Don't forget to refresh your ignore files, these should be ignored:

```
.cache
cache.cfg
connect.cfg
```

If you want to use Magento Connect from your admin, you can set the new URL here:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Connect/controllers/Adminhtml/Extension/LocalController.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just change the name of the folder from /downloader to /customurl

Please refer to this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095977/how-i-change-the-magento-connect-manager-location

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very good steps in the article for **Restrict access to Magento downloader**

https://magentary.com/kb/restrict-access-to-magento-downloader/